# How was the modular arithmetic law invented?

Tags: mathematics

We know that $(A \times B) \mod C = (A \mod C \times B \mod C) \mod C$. I know its proof.

But my question is: Who first noticed this modular property. Which problems led him to introduce the rule? How did he discover this rule?

Comment: I think it was Gauss, but await more knowledgeable answers.

Comment: Gauss was the first to define the concept of congruence and prove this theorem (it's an early result in his *Disquisitiones*), but I believe Euler and others used congruences implicitly - I just don't know how implicitly.

Comment: Euler used congruences explicitly since 1750, just without the Gauss's notation https://books.google.com/books?id=VG9YBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=euler+congruences+1750&source=bl&ots=WFT3jGcNvx&sig=mygTLCnP3kYkh8NUt8Tk77LVR_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0fPfVMa7HpP_yQSDs4DoDQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=euler%20congruences%201750&f=false

Comment: If we are looking for early implicit understanding that remainder of the product is the product of remainders I would suspect Sun Zi (3rd AD) of the Chinese remainder theorem, and Theaetetus (4th BC), who implicitly uses modular arithmetic in general incommensurability proofs.